# Vertical equivalent of "control+w n"?

Tags: split, vim-windows

I often want a new empty vertical pane (vim window / viewport ...) in my current Vim tab.

I know I can get a new empty horizontal pane by doing `control+w n`.

I know I can split the current pane into two identical vertical copies with `control+w v`, but then I always resort to the awkward workaround of opening a new empty horizontal pane within this vertical pane and then closing the duplicate view of the original pane which I didn't want.

Is there a built in way to just get a blank vertical pane?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From [`:help vnew`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/windows.txt.html#%3Avnew):

```
    Like |:new|, but split vertically.  If 'equalalways' is set
    and 'eadirection' isn't "ver" the windows will be spread out
    horizontally, unless a width was specified.
```

However, it seems like Vim does not provide a mapping for `:vnew` which creates a new *blank* vertical split. It's easy to create this mapping yourself. For instance:

```
nnoremap <leader>v :vnew<CR>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution:

1. <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>w</kbd> <kbd>v</kbd> Create a vertical copy of your current window
2. <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>w</kbd> <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>w</kbd> Move to new pane
3. <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>w</kbd> <kbd>n</kbd> Create a new horizontal white pane above the second
4. <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>w</kbd> <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>w</kbd> Return to second pane
5. <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>w</kbd> <kbd>c</kbd> Close second pane

This can be made into a mapping if desired:

```
nnoremap <leader>v <C-w>v<C-w>w<C-w>n<C-w>w<C-w>c
```

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! I made some [edit]s to your post, though I would agree that `:vnew` is simpler.