# how can I make keymap to open a new file in a vertical split?

Tags: vimrc, vim-windows

I tried

```
nnoremap <c-m><c-m> <c-w>vs  ene
```

and

```
nnoremap <c-m><c-m> <c-w>vs<space>ene
```

but I don't get a new file, I get the same file in a new buffer.

Comment: I see this is answered [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2811/vertical-equivalent-of-controlw-n)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command you are looking for is `:vertical new` or `:vnew`.  The latter has the advantage that is easier to make a command which takes a count, e.g., `:20vnew`.  In the following mapping,

`nnoremap <c-m><c-m> :vnew<cr>`

typing a count beforehand, e.g. `20<c-m><c-m>` will specify the width of the new window.  To ignore this count and always split evenly, you can use `<c-u>` to remove the line numbers which are placed in the command line after the mapping's `:`.

`nnoremap <c-m><c-m> :<c-u>vnew<cr>`

Comment: I also tried nnoremap <c-m><c-m> :vnew<CR> which seems to be working. what does the <c-u> mean?

Comment: Indeed, see my amended answer, it just comes down to whether you want to support a count or not.

Comment: One new problem now is that I get a vertical split when I press <CR> twice in succession in normal mode.